# concatenating large number of tables in sas

Tags: sql, sas

let's assume i have a large list of tables say :

```
%let y = jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
```

all these tables have the same column names and number of columns, i want to stack all these tables one under the other in one dataset

i tried to create a macro to do so (because i have multiple other lists that are larger than this but up until now i've failed to do so

```
%let y = jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
%macro con_tabs(in);
%local i s;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&in.,%str( )));
    %let s&i.=%scan(&in.,&i.,%str( ));
    
    proc sql;
        create table tab&i. as 
        select * from &&s&i...a union all 
        select * from &&s&(i+1)...b;
    quit;

%end;
%mend con_tabs;
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are trying to use SQL instead of just using normal SAS code?

Comment: no it's just that i did not know how to proceed with it using normal sas code ( and i thought that it would be simpler using proc sql )

Comment: SQL code is rarely simpler.  It is sometimes better, for example for many to many joins or joins that are not exact matches of key variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue to use SQL for this task you will want to properly construct the SQL statement for many tabled `UNION ALL`.

Do **not** iteratively 'append' one table at time using a single UNION ALL of the stack and next table. Instead do all stacking in a single SQL statement.

Example:

```
data t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6;
  retain x 1;
run;

%macro sql_stack(table_list=, out=);

  %local index table;

  proc sql;

  %do index = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&table_list));

      %if &index = 1 %then 
        CREATE TABLE &OUT AS  /* sql code gen */
      ;
      %else
        UNION ALL  /* sql code gen */
      ;

      %let table = %scan(&table_list, &index);
      
      SELECT 
      "&table" as source,
      *
      FROM &table  /* sql code gen */
  %end;

  ; /* end code gen statement */
  QUIT;
%mend sql_stack;

%sql_stack(table_list=t1 t2 t3 t4 t5, out=want);
```

Will code gen

```
CREATE TABLE want AS 
          SELECT "t1" as source, * FROM t1 
UNION ALL SELECT "t2" as source, * FROM t2
UNION ALL SELECT "t3" as source, * FROM t3
UNION ALL SELECT "t4" as source, * FROM t4
UNION ALL SELECT "t5" as source, * FROM t5
;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a data step.

```
%let y = jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec ;
data want;
  set &y ;
run;
```